# What happens with the video if a browser doesn't support preload="none" tag?

Tags: html, css, video

I want to add a `video` to a HTML page.

I want it to be loaded only if the user presses the play button, not directly from the beginning on.

For that I use `preload="none"`.

On [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp) they say that it is not supported on Internet explorer.

So when someone enters the page, what will he see then?

Does the `video` load from the beginning on or doesn't he even see the `video` (maybe just a black space or something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set `poster` for [`video`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) tag

> thanks, but I want the following: video should only load if user
>   clicks on play (thats done with preload). BUT if preload is not
>   supported, I want the video to load directly from the beginning on. is
>   this possible?

Ok then you can remove the `poster` and add:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play();
```

in each condition that will test if the user agent is Internet Explorer

```js
/**
 * detect IE
 * returns version of IE or false, if browser is not Internet Explorer
 */
function detectIE() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    if (msie > 0) {
      // IE 10 or older => return version number
      document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play();
    }
    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    if (trident > 0) {
      // IE 11 => return version number
      document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play();
    }
    var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
    if (edge > 0) {
      // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
      document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play();
    }
    // other browser
    return false;
  }
  //Call the function
detectIE();
```

```html
<video width="480" preload="none" controls>
  <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: so in case the browser doesnt support preload, there will only be shown the poster?? and it is not possible to play the video then?

Comment: yes exactly `:)`. It is possible when you click play

Comment: thanks, but I want the following: video should only load if user clicks on play (thats done with preload). BUT if preload is not supported, I want the video to load directly from the beginning on. is this possible?